# How to disable chunked encoding in Mule cxf:proxy-client

Tags: http, https, http-headers, mule

I'm using `Mule 3.3.2` `cxf:proxy-client` to call third-party Soap service this way:

```
<outbound-endpoint address="https://www.xyz.biz/Dms/Call.aws" mimeType="text/xml" connector-ref="https.connector" responseTimeout="100000">
            <cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false">
                <cxf:inInterceptors>
                    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
                </cxf:inInterceptors>
                <cxf:outInterceptors>
                    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
                </cxf:outInterceptors>
            </cxf:proxy-client>
        </outbound-endpoint>
```

By default, the message is transmitted as `chunked` which is good but unfortunately server cannot handle that. How can I disable chunking in `proxy-client` so that instead of `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, `Content-Length` header is passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be done easily by forcing the http version to 1.0

Simply add the following transformer

```
<message-properties-transformer>
      <!-- Add the http version property to the message -->
      <add-message-property key="http.version" value="HTTP/1.0" />
</message-properties-transformer>
```

before your outbound endpoint

Comment: On Mule 3.3.x and later, I'd rather use `set-property`.